# Is there another way to change the date format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: excel

I need help with changing mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy - I have tried all the formulas and I just get an error all the time

I tried:
=DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(F47433,4)),VALUE(LEFT(F47433,FIND("/",F47433)-1)),VALUE(MID(F47433,FIND("/",F47433)+1,2)))
=DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(L9,4)), VALUE(MID(L9,4,2)), VALUE(LEFT(L9,2)))
I also did the extra date function and choose the type
I also did the covert and changed form MDY to DMY

I just need to find a faster way to change the date formate

Answer (score 1):

Try use `=text()` when **date** to **mm/dd/yyyy**

```
# A1 is your cell contains a date
=TEXT( A1 ; "mm/dd/yyyy" )
```

Try use `=date()` when **mm/dd/yyyy** to **dd/mm/yyyy**

```
# A1 is your cell contains a text as mm/dd/yyyy
=DATE(  RIGHT(A1;4) ;  LEFT(A1;2) ;  MID(A1;4;2)  )
```

> Note that `=date()` will return a date and `=text()` will return a text